# {(intermediate value)} is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

I come from a python background and so I am familiar with classes and methods, I also have a simple background from javascript during my codeacademy lessons a few months back. However, I have little to no experiences with error handling.

I want to web-scrape (I always do this with python), and have built a simple scraper class - I at least think I got the `get` method correct?

This should return the output from the request, however I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: {(intermediate value)} is not a constructor
    at <anonymous> (undefined:4:16)
    at run (undefined:195:25)
    --- await ---
    at runMainESM (undefined:51:21)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (undefined:74:5)
    at <anonymous> (undefined:17:47)
```

I have looked online and it mentions I have not placed the semi-colon `;` after a `console.log`, however I seem to have done this correctly.

```
import pkg from 'superagent';
const { get } = pkg;

const header = new {
    'Content-Length': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
const url = new 'https://books.toscrape.com';

class Agent {
    constructor(url, headers){
        this.url = url;
        this.headers = headers;
        console.log(this.url);
        //this._body = body;
    }
    
    getAgent = () => {
        return get(this._url)
        .set(this.headers)
        .end((err, res) => {
            console.log(res.body);
        })
    }

    get smallAgent() {
       return this.getAgent()
    }
};

const request = new Agent(url, header);

console.log(request.getAgent());
```

Expected output:

```
> ... response body ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in these lines:

> const header = new {
> 'Content-Length': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
> };
> const url = new 'https://books.toscrape.com';

You can't just use `new` operator without giving him a constructor.
If you meant to create an object with certain field you just have to write something like this:

```js
const header = {  
     'Content-Length': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  
};
```

Assigning a string to variable is even easier:

```js
const url = 'https://books.toscrape.com';
```

There's no need to use `new` everywhere.

Don't clearly sure what `superagent` package is supposed to do but I think it would be good for you to read a bit more about `new` operator at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: Ah thank you for clarifying! I only did one course 3 months back and jumped back in today so I am still learning. Thank you for the reference, I have been using the documentation since returning to Javascript.